# Reading ESRI Geodatabase Metadata with QGIS

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase, metadata

I have used the ArcMap tool to create a geodatabase in an Postgres/PostGIS database and have loaded a feature class and an XML file that contains metadata for the feature class into the geodatabase using FME. Now when I right-click the feature class in the Catalog window of ArcMap, I can see the metadata.

It would be great if I could also see that metadata in QGIS. However, when I try to load it into the QGIS canvas it doesn't even show as a spatial table. I know it is a spatial table because I can load it into ArcMap. Is there any way that I can put this table on the map and also view its metadata in a similar way to ArcMap? I have used the Metatools plugin, but that is only for shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the plugin "MapSearchCatalogueClient" - the documentation looks like what you'd expect the QGIS catalog browser to look like. I went to my plugins and it was already installed, so I updated it. Unfortunately I don't have a "MetaSearch" icon or menu item under "Web" - as was foretold in the "Startup" section of the docs.
Here is the link to them:
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_metasearch.html